# how to use lines in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

How to use find a line in Mathematica?

Comment: Including the code you tried to write in doing this would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

How about entering "= find a line" in Mathematica?

[image]

A snarky response, but I'm somewhat surprised that such a vague answer (to a vague question) can in this case yield an instructive minimal working example.